# How can I prevent the selection of all radio buttons in radio button lists that have the same ID value?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I have multi radio button lists. every one of them is showing on drop down list index changed. My problem is when I select a radio button from a specific radio button list, all of the other radio buttons lists select their own radio button that have the same ID value with the one I selected.
so when I select one, all others select their own.
I am using Vb.NET web forms and I set the radio button lists auto post back true and they are being created dynamically.
And when I make a unique ID it does not allow me to select so when I select it make the radio button not selected.

Comment: Don't use the same ID. The whole point of an ID is that it is supposed to be unique. Two fields with the same ID are considered to be the same field, hence selecting one selects all the other instances of the same field.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps one of those cases in which the stated goal is more valuable.

You don't mention or note where you data is comming from.

Lets say I have a list of hotels. And I want a radio button list of the "rating" for the hotel.

Well, in the forms desinger - drop in a gridview. Generate the columns. (then delete that data source from the markup. and in properties sheet remove the dataSource1 setting.

Ok, so far? That's about 2 minutes of time.

Now, drop in a radio buttion list. (somtimes I drop it on the form outside of the grid. Select the radio list and then add the choices (0-5 rating).

Now move that radio button list into the grid view. You have to wrap it around a item template.

So note how I used the builders here most of the time. (EVEN for the choices in the radiobutton list I used the builder from the designer).

Ok, so now our markup looks like this:

```
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" SortExpression="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rating For Hotel">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                SelectedValue = '<%# Bind("Rating") %>'
                >
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">No Rating</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Poor</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Fair</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Good</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">Excellent</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update Choices" />
<br />
```

So far? This has been near all drag + drop. As noted, I used the RadioButton list builder like this:

[image]

Then I added my choices:

[image]

THEN as noted, I cut+ paste that radio button list into the grid as per above.

Now, in my on-load, I have this code:

```
   If IsPostBack = False Then

        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT TOP 10 ID, HotelName, City, Rating from tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName"

        Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Test3))
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()

        GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        GridView1.DataBind()
        GridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False

        cmdSQL.Connection.Close()
        Session("cmd") = cmdSQL

    End If
```

And now I get this:
[image]

Think about how easy this was.
I only so far written about 7 lines of code.

Now the user can change/choose the radio button settings.

How do I now update the rows BACK to the database?

Well, the update button will look like this:

```
    Dim dr As GridViewRow
    Dim cmdSQL As SqlCommand = Session("cmd")
    cmdSQL.Connection.Open()

    Dim rst As New DataTable
    rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)

    For Each dr In GridView1.Rows
        Dim rbL As RadioButtonList = dr.FindControl("RadioButtonList2")
        rst.Rows(dr.RowIndex).Item("Rating") = rbL.SelectedValue
    Next

    Dim daUpdate As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
    Dim cmdUpdate As New SqlCommandBuilder(daUpdate)

    daUpdate.Update(rst)
    cmdSQL.Connection.Close()

    'cmdSQL.Dispose()
```

So, that will send the choices back to the database.

Again, look at how little code and effort this was.

So, you might want to expand on WHAT you want to do after a user makes a choice in that radio button. So you want to see/check the values?

Do you want to send the choices back to a database?

As you can see in above, we really don't care (or need) some event for each radio button list.

And if this is some kind of survay system? Then again I would drive the choices from a database. If there are say 5 answers or whatever, then display the results as per above.

And remember, be it a listview, gridview, or even a block of controls as a "repeater"?

Then the above code pattern is quite much the same.

Now, in above I can/could FIRE the row event for a given choice in the radio button list - but at this point in time I am not convinced that this is actually a requirement - but you can get/grab that event if you wish, and take action on each row and as a result of selecting the radio button list (changing values).

EVEN if you goal is not to update a datebase and have a "N" (un-known) list of choices, some type of data grid or list view or data repeater will slice and dice this problem with great ease - and as you can see?

I wrote VERY little code. And I let VS and the form designer write 99% of my markup for me - there was little hand coding of the mark-up - I let the designers and wizards do all the dirty work for me.